# how update dynamically attribute in jsonb data column with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Hi i have this structure in my column jsonb in postgres

```
offer_profile_id (PK, FK): bigint
website_id (PK, FK):    bigint
offer_profile_website_detail: jsonb {
    display_vat_included: boolean
    available_services: [{
        service_id: long
        included_by_default: boolean
        extra_service : boolean
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to add a new attribute named `is_active: boolean` inside the available_services.
The problem is that the table named "offer_profile", full of data with many rows and which can take a long time to write the `insert into "offer_profile" VALUES` script.

I'm looking for a dynamic way to update my table.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonb_set function available in Postgresql. Here is the [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html). Below is the non-tested version of the code, tweak the path as needed.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET offer_profile_website_detail = jsonb_set(
offer_profile_website_detail, '{available_services, 0, is_active}', 'true', true)
```

Test:

```
create table test
(
    offer_profile_id             bigint,
    website_id                   bigint,
    offer_profile_website_detail jsonb
)

insert into test values (1, 1, '{"display_vat_included": true, "available_services": [{"service_id": 123}]}');
insert into test values (2, 2, '{"display_vat_included": false, "available_services": [{"service_id": 345}]}');
insert into test values (3, 3, '{"display_vat_included": false, "available_services": [{"service_id": 567}]}');

SELECT offer_profile_id, offer_profile_website_detail,
jsonb_set(offer_profile_website_detail, '{available_services, 0, is_active}', 'true', true)
from test
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, I tested it but not working for me. The error is :path element at position 2 is not an integer. Can you update your comment please ?